# OpenCV.js vs OpenCV Python image imread rgb difference

Tags: javascript, python, opencv

I'm trying to understand why open cv give me different results in JS and Python during imread operation.
Just for illustration two screenshots from opencvjs site and colab where I extracting rgb (or brg) data for one jpg image and summarize all values just to see that there is a difference.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("/content/player3.jpg")
print(img.sum())
```

VS

```
let src = cv.imread('canvasInput');
let dst = new cv.Mat();

cv.cvtColor(src, dst, cv.COLOR_RGBA2BGR, 0);

let sum = dst.data.reduce((acc,i)=> acc=acc+i)
console.log('sum of the values',sum)
```

Result:50950421 vs 50949889

Any ideas how to get in JS same result as in the Python?
[see JS vs Python screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9o8v.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. could you, please, try add start value, like it's done in documentation of reduce
   https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce
2. I'm not sure what dst should return, but just to be sure, you can try to make strong convert to number, just in case

Try this out

```
let src = cv.imread('canvasInput');
let dst = new cv.Mat();

cv.cvtColor(src, dst, cv.COLOR_RGBA2BGR, 0);

let sum = dst.data.reduce((acc,i)=> acc=acc+(+i), 0)
console.log('sum of the values',sum)
```